# how to take data from CSV file without retaking, using multiple threads in jMeter?

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a CSV file with data, that is dynamic and is changed every test run (it could be `3k or 80+k lines`). This data - is uuid, that I extract from CSV and set as a variables to my http requests. HTTP request has `DELETE` method, so after getting each uuid from CSV file - I can't use it again cause I would have a `404 status code`. I've already set up `CSV Data Set Config` and there is no problems when I do it in 1 thread `(Number of Threads (users): 1)`. But, for proper performance testing I need to run test in multiple threads, i.e. `30 or 50`. And the point is - that I don't know how to set up logic to be agile and if I have a CSV file with `50k+` uuids that should be used in one Thread Group that has 30 threads - each thread will take only assigned to him uuids, won't retake them and won't take not assigned to him uuids.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) (and this is what you should be using for 80+k lines file) with default [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) setting of "All Threads"

each JMeter thread (virtual user) will be taking next line on each iteration which means that each UUID will be used only once no matter how many users are there.

If you additionally set `Recycle on EOF` to "False" and `Stop thread on EOF` to "True" your test will be stopped when JMeter reaches the end of the CSV file so no duplicate requests will be sent.

[image]

Comment: Thx for you response! It is really helpful indeed..) However I have a problem.. When I set `Recycle on EOF` to "False" + `Stop thread on EOF` to "True" and `Sharing mode` to "All threads" - somehow it stops the whole test run.. 0_o though I changed it to "Current thread group" and it worked as I expected. Nevertheless, your answer seems like it is what I need so thx a lot!